# Possible security attack on redis

Tags: redis

Running the command `redis-server` it returns:

`The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379`

Trying to connect in my browser localhost:6379 I get this message:

`Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.`

Can anyone help me fix this error please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need to use a Redis client to connect to Redis, not your browser. Look at this page for a few https://redis.io/clients, or use [`redis-cli`](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli), or even just plain Telnet.

Comment: I am getting this exception while using jedis client.

Comment: I tried dash-extensions websocket to get message from redis. I got the same error. Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by installing [Redis Insight](https://redis.io/docs/connect/insight/) to make requests in the graphical environment.