# HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)

Tags: azure, redis, django-channels, azure-container-service, azure-webapps

I created the Azure web app container service. Where I am trying to build redis image along with private Django channels image. I am getting the above error and the container is stopping. These are my logs in the web app container.`enter code here`

```
2020-07-08T01:24:20.575Z ERROR -`enter code here` multi-container unit was not started successfully
2020-07-08T01:24:20.585Z INFO - Container logs from kiwi-message-delivery_redis_0_530c2465 = 2020-07-08T01:20:34.613961396Z 1:C 08 Jul 2020 01:20:34.613 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
2020-07-08T01:20:34.622739022Z 1:C 08 Jul 2020 01:20:34.622 # Redis version=6.0.5, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
2020-07-08T01:20:34.623124845Z 1:C 08 Jul 2020 01:20:34.622 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
2020-07-08T01:20:34.708013928Z 1:M 08 Jul 2020 01:20:34.707 Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
2020-07-08T01:20:34.708440853Z 1:M 08 Jul 2020 01:20:34.708 # Server initialized
2020-07-08T01:20:34.708763573Z 1:M 08 Jul 2020 01:20:34.708 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add &#39;vm.overcommit_memory = 1&#39; to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command &#39;sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1&#39; for this to take effect.
2020-07-08T01:20:34.709083492Z 1:M 08 Jul 2020 01:20:34.708 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command &#39;echo never &gt; /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled&#39; as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
2020-07-08T01:20:34.709659826Z 1:M 08 Jul 2020 01:20:34.709 Ready to accept connections
2020-07-08T01:20:37.186901553Z 1:M 08 Jul 2020 01:20:37.186 # Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.
2020-07-08T01:21:38.792293857Z 1:M 08 Jul 2020 01:21:38.792 # Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.
2020-07-08T01:22:39.333304667Z 1:M 08 Jul 2020 01:22:39.333 # Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.
2020-07-08T01:23:40.870740206Z 1:M 08 Jul 2020 01:23:40.870 # Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.
2020-07-08T01:24:24.447Z INFO - Container logs from kiwi-message-delivery_channels_0_530c2465 = 2020-07-08T01:20:43.833567596Z 2020-07-08 01:20:43,832 INFO Starting server at tcp:port=8000:interface=0.0.0.0
2020-07-08T01:20:43.834721057Z 2020-07-08 01:20:43,834 INFO HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2020-07-08T01:20:43.841353805Z 2020-07-08 01:20:43,840 INFO Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=0.0.0.0
2020-07-08T01:20:43.843852936Z 2020-07-08 01:20:43,843 INFO Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:8000
2020-07-08T01:24:29.155Z INFO - Stopping site kiwi-message-delivery because it failed during startup.
```

I tried with enabling the HTTP 2.0 in Web App configuration. But not working.

Anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running redis directly in container service to see if that works? I am more concerned about Security Attack message which would mean as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789027/possible-security-attack-on-redis), someone (either health check or something else) is trying to connect to redis as http endpoint.

In channels, HTTP/2 message is just a info log so that should not be an issue.

Also can you share more information about image that you are trying to build so any settings issue can be identified.